# Placing layout below AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have currently this layout set

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.beastovest.copilot.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiMSe.png)

by removing:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

it stars to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjVMc.png)

The button is still clickable however it is not visible.

I am trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zR3U.png) look

The action bar to be in front of all content

Comment: Try setting a fixed height to `AppbarLayout` `height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guy posted a solution which was to replace the CoordinatorLayout with Relative layout and it worked.

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.beastovest.copilot.activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```